# How to highlight all instances of variables that are clicked on?

Tags: android, android-studio, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

[image: Netbeans]
[image: Android Studio]

First image is my Netbeans IDE. As you can see whenever I place the text cursor on a variable, that variable is highlighted everywhere else where it appears.
I find this feature very helpful and want to enable it on Android Studio (second image).

Comment: android studio > file > setting > editor

Comment: @EliasFazel I've tried looking in there, can't find the setting to do this.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @SahanSerasinghe 2.3.3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried `Identifier under caret` setting?

Probably some mismatch with the colors you have set for Foreground and Background

Check my screenshot and let me know how it goes

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! That was it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Have  you try this =>

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Highlight on Caret Movement

Then for my personal use, I checked the three options :

-Highlight matched brace
-Highlight current scope
-Highlight usages os element at caret

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olXvu.jpg)

Comment: I had 'Highlight current scope' unchecked, now I checked it, reset Android Studio and variables are still not highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was File -> Editor -> Code Editing -> Highlight on Caret Movement -> usages of element at caret